# What bands should be used to identify clouds using the cloud function of the landsat package in LANDSAT 8 scenes?

Tags: r, landsat, landsat-8, cloud-cover

I am trying to use the `clouds` function of the `landsat` r package to identify clouds in my LANDSAT 8 scene.

In the package help, it is said that reflectance bands 1 and 6 should be used:

> `clouds(band1, band6, level = 0.0014, buffer=5)`

where bands 1 and 6 are data frames.

I have done so, with the following code:

```
p198r054_sr<-stack("LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band1.tif",
                   "LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band2.tif",
                   "LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band3.tif",
                   "LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band4.tif",
                   "LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band5.tif",
                   "LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band6.tif",
                   "LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band7.tif")
p198r054_band1<-p198r054_sr$LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band1
p198r054_band6<-p198r054_sr$LC08_L1TP_198054_20140205_20170426_01_T1_sr_band6
p198r054_band1<-as.data.frame(p198r054_band1, row.names=NULL, optional=FALSE, xy=TRUE, 
                              na.rm=FALSE, long=FALSE)
p198r054_band6<-as.data.frame(p198r054_band6, row.names=NULL, optional=FALSE, xy=TRUE, 
                              na.rm=FALSE, long=FALSE)
```

Using my two bands gives me the following message (using default threshold):

```
p198r054_clouds<-clouds(p198r054_band1, p198r054_band6, buffer=5)

Error in x[(i - mwoffset):(i + mwoffset), (j - mwoffset):(j + mwoffset)] : 
      subscript out of bounds
```

Could this error be due to the fact that I am using the wrong bands?
I don't know if the package was meant for LANDSAT 7 or 8 images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check function documentation:

> **References**
>
> This function is loosely based on: Martinuzzi, S., Gould, W.A., Ramos
>   Gonzales, O.M. 2007. Creating Cloud-Free Landsat ETM+ Data Sets in
>   Tropical Landscapes: Cloud and Cloud-Shadow Removal. USDA Forest
>   Service General Technical Report IITF-GTR-32.

From Martinuzzi et al. 2007:

> ... We have developed a simple and semiautomated method to mask clouds
>   and shadows in Landsat ETM+ imagery... We created cloud masks by using
>   Landsat ETM+ band 1 (blue) and thermal band 6.1 ...
>
> **Cloud Masking**
>
> • Brightness values for clouds were identified by visual analysis. For
>   band 1, DN values between 120 and 255 include clouds as well as urban,
>   barren, quarries, rocks, and sand. For band 6, DN values of 102 to 128
>   include both clouds and densely forested areas.

Also, `landsat` package is from 2012, I recommend you to use `RStoolbox` (Last update 2017-08-22). You can use [`cloudMask`](http://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/rstbx-docu/cloudMask.html) function:

[image]